# Some React components not re-rendering after setState change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, web-frontend

I have a form that has a two buttons on top, Sign Up / Log In, and one button on the bottom, Get Started. I am struggling to get the components to update with eachother. From the default Sign Up component, I can click on the Get Started button and the form disappears and shows the product components as it should. My issue is I cannot get the Log In component to display instead of the Sign Up.

The below is the code I am using - you will see where I have commented out  two of my if statements where my intentions were trying to just have the app load whatever state its in. The last return with the ? statement seems to be tripping me up when I attempt to add the third component. I am able to correctly set the state to "loginShow", although nothing changes it just records in my console.

How can I correctly set state so it just toggles back and forth between Sign Up and Log In untill I press the Get Started button at the bottom?

```js
clickMe = () => {
        const {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko} = this.state;
        this.setState({ requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: !requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko })
    }
    mainLogIn = () => {
    //  const {loginStatus} = this.state;
        this.setState({ loginStatus: 'loginShow' })
    }
    render() {
        const { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko } = this.state;
        const { loginStatus } = this.state;
        console.log(loginStatus);
//      if (loginStatus === "loginHide") return <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()} />
        if (loginStatus === "loginShow") return <Login /> 
//      if (requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko.props === true) return <Cards /> 
          return (

           <div className="gecko">
            {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko ? (
              <Cards />
            ): (
             <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()} />
            )
            }
          </div> 
        ); 
      }
```

Comment: where you are firing `mainLogIn` function, to set the `loginStatus` to `loginShow`??

Comment: @adel from within my SignUp component page when the user clicks the Log In button. I dont think I am firing from this page

Comment: sorry but  Singup  component prop `login={() => this.clickMe()} ` is firing `clickMe` function not `mainLogIn `  function .